# How to show the total number of pages in a PDF via the RMarkdown (i.e. display "Page 1 of 10")?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, tex

Given the code below, which currently outputs the page number on top of the page, I would like it to output the PDF page count as in `Page 1 of 3`. I have done a lot of searching but haven't found any way to include the total page number.

**Question** Is this possible to do w/ in R Markdown ? If not, are there any workarounds ?

I have googled this and haven't found anything obvious such as YAML or TeX solutions, however, I may be missing something or not searching for the correct things.

**RMarkdown Code**

```
---
title: "R Markdown Example With Numbered Sections"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 6
    number_sections: true
    includes:
        in_header: header.tex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage}
- \fancyhead[LO,LE]{Header Message}
- \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{Footer Messge on the Left}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Footer Messge on the Right}
---

\thispagestyle{fancy}

# Example R Rarkdown : Numbered Sections

## R Markdown

### Description

Some description text

\newpage

#### Details

Details go here.

\newpage

## Plots

Plots go here

\newpage

Last page
```

**Current header**

[image]

**Desired Header**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the `lastpage` package installed.

Then modify your header includes to look like this:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
  - \fancyhead[LO,LE]{Header Message}
  - \fancyfoot[LE,LO]{Footer Messge on the Left}
  - \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Footer Messge on the Right}
```